# Knockout view not removing item from view after delete

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5, typescript

I have this code that successfully deletes an exam from a list of exams displayed on a page, but the page still shows the deleted exam.  You have to manually refresh the page for the view to update.   We are using a simlar pattern on other pages and it's working correctly.  I don't understand why it doesn't work on this page.

```
 // Used to handle the click event for Delete
    remove = (exam: Models.Exam) => {
        $("#loadingScreen").css("display", "block");
        var examService = new Services.ExamService();

        examService.remove(exam.examId()).then(() => {
            examService.getByFid().then((examinations: Array<Models.Exam>) => {


                this.exams(examinations);

                this.template("mainTemplate");
            });
        }).fail((error: any) => {
                // Add this error to errors
                this.errors([error]);
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }).fin(() => {
                $("#loadingScreen").css("display", "none");
            });
    }
```

Here's the UI code that displays the list of exams

```
    <div class="section module">
        <!-- ko if: exams().length > 0 -->
        <!-- ko foreach: exams.sort(function(a,b){return a.mostRecentDateTaken() > b.mostRecentDateTaken() ? 1:-1}) -->
        <div class="addremove_section bubbled">
            <a class="button open_review" data-bind="click: $root.edit">Edit</a>
            <a class="button open_review" data-bind="click: $root.remove">Delete</a>
            <div class="titleblock">
                <h4 data-bind="text: 'Exam Name: ' + examTypeLookup().examTypeName()"></h4>
                <div data-bind="if:examEntityLookup()!=null">
                    <div data-bind=" text: 'Reporting Entity: ' + examEntityLookup().description()"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="text: 'Most recent date taken: ' +  $root.formatDate(mostRecentDateTaken())"></div>
                <div data-bind="text: 'Number of attempts: ' + numberOfAttempts()"></div>
                <div data-bind="text: 'Pass/Fail Status: ' + $root.PassFailEnum(passFailId())"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: exams().length == 0 -->
        <div class="addremove_section bubbled">
            <div class="titleblock">
                <div>No Exams Have Been Entered.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
```

EDIT:  I discovered that if I remove the sort from this line in the view

```
<!-- ko foreach: exams.sort(function(a,b){return a.mostRecentDateTaken() > b.mostRecentDateTaken() ? 1:-1}) -->
```

to

```
<!-- ko foreach: exams -->
```

it works!  The only problem is that I need the data sorted.

Comment: Have you confirmed that indeed examinations doesn't contain the removed element after deletion, and that this.exams(examinations); actually alters the exams observable? maybe your "this" is not actually pointing to what you expect and should instead do: var self = this; prior to calling the service and use "self" instead

Comment: I removed the sort <!-- ko foreach: exams.sort(function(a,b){return a.mostRecentDateTaken() > b.mostRecentDateTaken() ? 1:-1}) --> from this line and it works!  very strange.

Comment: I've never tried sorting while binding in such a way, since sorting actually changes the array. 
Try sorting before or after you populate the observable this.exams(examinations); instead of in the view, or using a computed observable. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the sorting from the view and did the sorting in the service.   Not really sure why I can't sort in the view.  I assume it's a knockout.js bug.

```
<!-- ko foreach: exams -->


        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/exam")]
        public IEnumerable<TDto> GetApplicantExams()
        {

                var dtos = GetCollection(() => _examService.GetApplicantExams(UserContext.Fid).OrderBy(e => e.DateTaken));
                return dtos.ForEach(t => AddItems(t));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug in Knockout.  Since the sort invocation (as you're doing it) is not under the control of a computed/dependent observable, there's nothing to trigger it to resort.  You've basically broken the connection between the UI (or more technically, the bindingHandler) and the `ko.observable` which KO uses for tracking changes.

I've run into this many times where I work,  and the general pattern I use is something like this:

```
var viewmodel = {
    listOfObjects:ko.observableArray(),
    deleteFromList:deleteFromList,
    addToList:addToList,
}

//in your HTML,  you'll do a foreach: listOfSortedObjects (instead of listOfObjects)
viewmodel.listOfSortedObjects = ko.computed(function(){
    //Since this is *inside* the change tracking ecosystem, this sort will be called as you would expect
    return viewmodel.listOfObjects().sort(yourSortingFunction);
});

//Since you cannot edit a (normal) computed,  you need to do your work on the original array as below.

function deleteFromList(item){
    viewmodel.listOfObjects.remove(item);//Changing this array will trigger the sorted computed to update, which will update your UI
}
function addToList(item){
    viewmodel.listOfObjects.push(item);
}
```